# R: Write function output from serial function calls to data.frame

Tags: r

One of my students sent me his R script along with his homework where he is obviously trying to gather relevant output from several serial function calls in a data.frame. It works but I think it is a quite ugly solution. I give you a working example:

```
# Create sample data
ref <- sample(c(0,1), 20, T)
cat1 <- sample(c("ab", "cd", "ef"), 20, T)
cat2 <- sample(c("mm", "nn"), 20, T)
cat3 <- sample(c("low", "mid", "high"), 20, T)
table <- data.frame(ref, cat1, cat2, cat3)

# The ugly code
library(gmodels)
result <- data.frame(a = NA, b = NA, statistic = NA, p.value = NA)

x <- CrossTable(table$ref, table$cat1, chisq=T, prop.r=F, prop.chisq=F, prop.t=F)
result <- rbind(result, data.frame(a = names(x$prop.col[2,]),b = x$prop.col[2,], c = x$chisq[1], d = x$chisq[3],row.names = NULL))

x <- CrossTable(table$ref, table$cat2, chisq=T, prop.r=F, prop.chisq=F, prop.t=F)
result <- rbind(result, data.frame(a = names(x$prop.col[2,]),b = x$prop.col[2,],c = x$chisq[1],d = x$chisq[3],row.names = NULL))

x <- CrossTable(table$ref, table$cat3, chisq=T, prop.r=F, prop.chisq=F, prop.t=F)
result <- rbind(result, data.frame(a = names(x$prop.col[2,]),b = x$prop.col[2,],c = x$chisq[1],d = x$chisq[3],row.names = NULL))

# The result
> result
     a         b statistic   p.value
1 <NA>        NA        NA        NA
2   ab 0.4444444 1.0646144 0.5872485
3   cd 0.2500000 1.0646144 0.5872485 
4   ef 0.5714286 1.0646144 0.5872485
5   mm 0.2857143 1.1743812 0.2785029
6   nn 0.5384615 1.1743812 0.2785029
7 high 0.4000000 0.1443001 0.9303913
8  low 0.5000000 0.1443001 0.9303913
9  mid 0.4285714 0.1443001 0.9303913
```

I guess that this data.frame was used to copy'n'paste the relevant result to Excel without having to go through each of the CrossTables by hand... I wanted to give some advice how to avoid such a hassle but, given this data structure, I haven't found a neat solution yet.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a data.frame is essentially a list of vectors, you can apply a function to each of the columns in turn with lapply, and convert the list back to a data.frame. This will avoid some of the duplication of code, and avoid the cumulative "rbinding".

```
library("dplyr") # Using dplyr for bind_rows
library("gmodels")

ref <- sample(c(0,1), 20, T)
cat1 <- sample(c("ab", "cd", "ef"), 20, T)
cat2 <- sample(c("mm", "nn"), 20, T)
cat3 <- sample(c("low", "mid", "high"), 20, T)
mytable <- data.frame(ref, cat1, cat2, cat3)

# Function to extract the statistical results comparing 
# the ref column to each of the other columns in turn

results_fun <- function(x) {
  x <- CrossTable(mytable$ref, x, chisq = TRUE, prop.r = FALSE,
       prop.chisq = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE)
  res <- data.frame(a = names(x$prop.col[2,]), b = x$prop.col[2, ], 
       c = x$chisq[1], d = x$chisq[3],row.names = NULL)
  res
}

mylist <- lapply(mytable[-1], results_fun)
myresults <- bind_rows(mylist)
```

giving

```
Source: local data frame [8 x 4]

      a         b statistic   p.value
  (chr)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1    ab 0.5000000 0.3428571 0.8424604
2    cd 0.4000000 0.3428571 0.8424604
3    ef 0.5714286 0.3428571 0.8424604
4    mm 0.4444444 0.2020202 0.6530951
5    nn 0.5454545 0.2020202 0.6530951
6  high 0.3333333 1.8666667 0.3932407
7   low 0.6666667 1.8666667 0.3932407
8   mid 0.6000000 1.8666667 0.3932407
```